# iOS - JSON Parsing for AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, parsing, afnetworking

I am trying to parse JSON from a server, however whenever I use AFNetworking the parser does not work, it returns the entire JSON rather than separating it.

I played around with the JSON and I noticed this .NET security feature

```
 {"d":[JSON INSIDE]}
```

JSON INSIDE = My JSON Data that has 3 data objects, not shown here.
is causing the default JSON Parser to just return the entire JSON as 1.
If I remove the {"d":}, it parses correctly into multiple parts. However, the return data from the server cannot have the d removed. Is there anywhere in AFNetworking that I can tell it to ignore the d part and only process the [JSON] inside the brackets?

Thanks,
Alan

Update: I am trying to reparse again after I get the data inside the "d:", but I am getting a SigAbort on the NSJSonSerialization line.

```
    NSString *innerData = [JSON objectForKey:@"d"];
    NSLog(@"Inner Description %@", innerData);

    NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
    NSDictionary *requestDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[innerData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&jsonParsingError];
```

Example JSON I am parsing:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"RequestSearchedInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Description":"testing prod ","DueDate":"","Priority":{"__type":"ComponentInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":2,"Name":"Medium"},"RequestId":368,"Requestor":{"__type":"ComponentInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":5863,"Name":"A Person's Name"},"SentDate":"8\/31\/2012 4:28:11 PM","Status":{"__type":"StatusInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":27,"IsEndState":false,"Name":"Pending Approval"},"System":{"__type":"ComponentInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":11,"Name":"Internal-Testing"}},{"__type":"RequestSearchedInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Description":"testing prod ","DueDate":"","Priority":{"__type":"ComponentInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":2,"Name":"Medium"},"RequestId":367,"Requestor":{"__type":"ComponentInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":5863,"Name":"A Persons Name"},"SentDate":"8\/31\/2012 4:27:40 PM","Status":{"__type":"StatusInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":2,"IsEndState":false,"Name":"Pending Review"},"System":{"__type":"ComponentInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":11,"Name":"Internal-Testing"}},{"__type":"RequestSearchedInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Description":"testin","DueDate":"08\/03\/2012","Priority":{"__type":"ComponentInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":3,"Name":"High"},"RequestId":29,"Requestor":{"__type":"ComponentInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":5863,"Name":"A Persons Name"},"SentDate":"8\/2\/2012 1:58:34 PM","Status":{"__type":"StatusInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":22,"IsEndState":false,"Name":"Acceptance Certification passed, Request to be Closed"},"System":{"__type":"ComponentInfo:#ChangeControlService.DataContracts","Id":11,"Name":"Internal-Testing"}}]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not very clear about what the input and the outputs you are experiencing is. Do you mean the above code returns `@{ @"d" : @1 }` after it's parsed?

Comment: The code will return the entire JSON unparsed if there is the {"d": } encapsulating the JSON. If I remove the {"d": } from surrounding the JSON data, it will parse correctly into separate objects. So say there are 3 objects in the JSON return. If the d is there, it will return everything {"d":[JSON data]} as one object rather than returning them as 3 objects [JSON data object 1], [JSON data object 2]. [JSON data object 3].

So basically, the parser doesn't parse at all. It just returns the all that data from the call as one object.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot continue to parse the json inside of the object that is held at "d"? Why not store the object as innerObj and continue to parse it?

Comment: So it's a string value `@{ @"d" : @"[JSON data object 1], [JSON data object 2]. [JSON data object 3]" }`? I really think you need to post a sample with the real JSON. It doesn't need to be your actual data, but I need to see the format to have a better understanding of what's happening.

Comment: I posted further progress and real JSON I am attempting to parse. So, it will return the entire thing below as 1 object, if I remove the d part, it will separate them into 3 objects as there are 3 in there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured it out... Thank you for all who responded.
Jeffery and Propstm

I just needed to do

```
id innerJSON = [JSON objectForKey:@"d"];
```

Thanks!
Alan